# Should GTK+ interface run in a separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gtk, gtkmm

I'm taking my first steps in GTK+ (`C++` and `gtkmm` more specificaly) and I have a rather conceptual doubts about how to best structure my program. Right now I just want my GUI to show what is happening in my C++ program by printing several values, and since my main thread is halted while the GUI window is running, I've come across solutions that separated both the processing/computing operations and the graphical interface in separate threads. Is this commonly accepted as the best way to do it, not at all, or not even relevant?

Comment: If you never do anything which takes more than a couple of seconds, and is usually sub-second, then don't use a separate thread. OTOH, if you have long running operations, spawn those in separate threads and post progress messages to the main thread. But think of the GUI thread as the main thread - the other threads are WORKER threads. The GUI is in control.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a good reason, you are generally better off not creating new threads. Synchronization is hard to get right.

GUI programming is event driven (click on a button and something happens). So you will probably need to tie your background processing into the GUI event system.

In the event that your background processing takes a long time, you will need to break it into a number of fast chunks. At the end of each chunk, you can update a progress bar and schedule the next chunk.

This will mean you will need to probably use some state machine patterns.

Also make sure that any IO is non-blocking.

Comment: ... all of which is hard to get right for any non-trivial interface, hence the ubiquity of sucky interfaces.

Comment: You can avoid state machine patterns by using "DoEvents" i.e. `gtk_main_iteration() ` at appropriate times. Cancel buttons should just set a cancel flag, which is then checked after DoEvents. Don't forget to disable the GUI (except for the progress dialog/cancel button) so the user cannot start overlapping tasks.

Comment: @Ben how would I run the main loop just once? I'm using `Gtk::Application->run(Gtk::Window)` and can't really find anything on the documentation. Apparently `iteration()` is a member of `Gtk::Main`.

Comment: If you have anything long running you have to yield every now and then otherwise you end up with said sucky user interface

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of lengthy operation split in smaller chunks using the main loop without additional threads. [Lazy Loading using the main loop](http://blogs.gnome.org/ebassi/documentation/lazy-loading/).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, absolutely!** (in response to your title)

The GUI *must* be run in a separate thread. If you have ever come across those extremely annoying interfaces that lock up while an operation is in progress<sup>1</sup>, you'd know why it's very important to have the GUI always running regardless of operation happening.

It's a user experience thing.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't mean the ones that disable some buttons during operation (that's normal), but the ones that everything seems frozen.

Comment: This has nothing to do with threading. Threading is only one solution to this problem, not THE solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reverse: **the main thread should be the Gtk one**, and the long processing/computing tasks should be done in threads.

The documentation gives a clear example:
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html